# Use only the variable that caused an if statement to trigger, within the if statement

Tags: javascript

say you have an if statement:

```
try {
    if (!a || !b || !c || !d) {
      let nullVariable = ???;
      // use the variable that is null
      throw nullVariable
    }
} catch (ex) {
  log.debug(`${ex} is not defined`);
}
```

Is there a built in way to see which variable was set to null, without creating an if statement for each individual variable?

Comment: No. What your are doing is good although `try/catch` should not be used for something like this. `try/catch` should only be used for situations that are outside of the developer's control, like doing networking or database operations. In your case, you can just test for the `null` value and have the program respond as needed. Throwing an exception is overkill.

Comment: Could two variables be falsy? If so, how should the code respond?

Comment: Put them in an array and search for `null`?? Like, `const nullVariableIndex = [a,b,c,d].indexOf(null);`

Comment: Are there guaranteed to be four variables? You could check each one in a `for` loop.  There's also the `array.find` and `array.findIndex` functions you could use

Comment: I have a separate script that triggers only in the case of an error, so my hope was to pass the error to the other script when thrown. I suppose if multiple are false, it would work through them in the order it found them. So if !a and !b, then the only thing shown in the other script would be a. Once that is resolved and rerun, the only thing shown would be b

Comment: In this specific case yes, there are guaranteed to only be 4 variables. I really like the indexOf(null) idea, i hadn't thought of that. That would even catch all missing variables

Comment: Would something like `let nullVariable = Object.entries({ a, b, c, d }).find(([_, val]) => !val)[0];` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the assignment inside the `if` condition expression.

```js
let a, b, c, d;
a = 3;
b = "foo";
d = {x: 10};
let nullVariable = (!a && 'a') || (!b && 'b') || (!c && 'c') || (!d && 'd');
if (nullVariable) {
    console.log(`${nullVariable} is not defined`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the variable name using object shorthand.

```js
const fn = ({ a, b, c, d }) => {
  let nullVariable = Object.entries({ a, b, c, d }).find(([_, val]) => !val)?.[0];
  
  if(nullVariable)
    console.log(nullVariable + ' is falsy');
};

fn({ a: 1, c: 2, d: 3 });
fn({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
fn({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 });
```